# Как соотнести данные одного столбца к другому

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Столбец А - короткий список идентификаторов
Столбец B - значение1 к идентификатору1
Столбец С - значение2 к идентификатору2
Столбец D - значение3 к идентификатору3
Столбец E - значение4 к идентификатору4
Столбец F - полный список идентификаторов.

Задача: Взять идентификатор из столбца А, взять значения к нему из столбцов B,C,D,E, найти этот же идентификатор в полном списке (столбец F) и добавить к нему значения в столбцы G,H,I,J соответственно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Функция ВПР() решает проблему. При условии, что значения столбца А уникальны. Иначе - задача нерешаема вследствие неоднозначности соответствия.

Comment: @Akina значения столбца А уникальны для столбца А, но они повторяются 1 раз в столбце F

Comment: @Akina Да и ВПР() найдет только различия, а данные не перенесет.

Comment: Почему данные не перенесет? В каждом столбце (G,H,I,J) написать ВПР() и все перенесет.

Comment: @СергейПряничкин сделал вот так   `=ВПР(F71;$A$2:$A$259;2)` выдает `#ссылка!`

Comment: Если столбец B нужен (допустим 71 строка) то в столбец G пишем:   =ВПР(F71;$A$2:$B$259;2;0)

Comment: [ВПР справка](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%9F%D0%A0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-excel-%E2%80%94-%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B8-office-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если указывать только первый столбец диапазона поиска, то да, функцией *ВПР* можно определять наличие или отсутствие значения в диапазоне (выводится искомое или ошибка *#Н/Д*).

Диапазон нужно правильно задавать. *ВПР* ищет искомое в первом столбце диапазона и показывает значение из нужного столбца. Для третьего столбца:

```
ВПР(F1;A$1:E$100;3;0)
```

Если столбцов в диапазоне немного, то не составит труда прописать константу (номер столбца) в каждой формуле. Для примера автора это будет 4 формулы для столбцов 2-5.

Номер столбца можно определять с помощью функции *СТОЛБЕЦ()*.

В столбце *F* список больше, в нем есть значения, отсутствующие в столбце *А*. При поиске того, чего нет, функция выдаст ошибку. Ошибку можно обойти дополнительной проверкой или с помощью функции провеки на ошибку:

```
=ЕСЛИ(СЧЁТЕСЛИ($A$1:$A$100;$F1);ВПР($F1;$A$1:$E$100;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1););) 

=ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ВПР($F1;$A$1:$E$100;СТОЛБЕЦ(B1););"")
```

При ошибке вместо нуля можно выводить пустой тект "" (показано во второй формуле). Не советую: наличие текста среди числовых значений может навредить при дальнейшем использовании данных (например, при вычислениях). Второе неудобство: для найденных идентификаторов, у которых в строке вместо значений пустые ячейки, будут показаны нули. Это тоже можно обойти, но с добавлением еще одной проверки.

Нулевые значения можно скрыть в параметрах листа (*Файл-Параметры-Дополнительно-Для_листа*, снять галку отображения нулевых значений).

Еще несколько вариантов с другими функциями:

```
=ИНДЕКС($B$1:$E$100;ПОИСКПОЗ($F1;$A$1:$A$100;);СТОЛБЕЦ(A1))

=ИНДЕКС(B$1:B$100;ПОИСКПОЗ($F1;$A$1:$A$100;))

=ПРОСМОТР($F1;$A$1:$A$100;B$1:B$100)
```

Обратите внимание на закрепления ссылок в формулах. Не нужно забывать об устранении возможной ошибки.